Error AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption issue when sending data from Angular
I have an Angular application running locally that needs to send data to an Azure Log Analytics Workspace. When I make the API call using Postman, it works perfectly fine. However, when I attempt to send the same request from within my Angular application, I encounter the following error:
AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type. Request origin: 'http://localhost:4200/'. Trace ID:  Correlation ID:  Timestamp: 2024-05-20 19:46:02Z

I have already ensured that I've added 'Single-Page Application' with 'http://localhost:4200/' as a redirect URI in Azure AD, and upon checking the application manifest, it's correctly set as "SPA".
Steps Taken:
Added 'Single-Page Application' client-type with 'http://localhost:4200/' redirect URI in Azure AD. add spa rediruct url

Confirmed that the redirect URI is marked as "SPA" in the Azure AD application manifest.
stackoverflow solution manifest

Expected Outcome:
The Angular application should be able to successfully send data to the Azure Log Analytics Workspace without encountering the cross-origin token redemption error.
I have spent considerable time troubleshooting this issue but haven't been able to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
auth: {
    clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID', // Replace with your Azure AD application client ID
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/YOUR_TENANT_ID', // Replace with your Azure AD tenant ID
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200', // The URL to redirect to after login
},
cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // Use localStorage to store the authentication state
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // Set to true to support browsers that block third-party cookies
}
};

// Create an instance of PublicClientApplication with the specified configuration
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
